# Sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wkhtmltopdf

Using wkhtmltopdf to convert my html to PDF.

Working fine on my local machine which is running on Windows 8.

But it is giving me 'Sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors' error while I try to run the same on Windows 2008 server R2.

Any idea how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with my server.

After configuring my application via host file, it started working.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Naresh, What did you do?

Comment: @Aaron sad OP didn't specify, but it put me on the right path. I had a similar issue and I needed to put the address in hosts file in Windows.

example: mydomain.com 127.0.0.1

and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that turned out to be caused by a DNS resolution issue.

For my particular case, I had to put valid DNS servers in my /etc/resolv.conf file.